# Calculate location and number of intersections between multiple date/time ranges?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to calculate the location of intersections between multiple date ranges, and the number of overlapping intersections. Then I need to show which date/time ranges overlap each of those intersecting sections. It is slightly more complicated than that so I'll do my best to explain by providing an example.  I am working in VB.Net, but C# examples are acceptable as well as I work in both.

We have several high risk tasks that involve the same system.  Below I have three example jobs named HR1/2/3/4 with start and end date/times.

- HR1 {1/6/2010 10:00 - 1/6/2010 15:00}
- HR2 {1/6/2010 11:00 - 1/6/2010 18:00}
- HR3 {1/6/2010 12:00 - 1/6/2010 14:00}
- HR4 {1/6/2010 18:00 - 1/6/2010 20:00}

What I want the end result to be is shown below.  I am having trouble describing it any way but by example.

- HRE1 {1/6/2010 10:00 - 1/6/2010 11:00} - Intersects 1
- {End Time Split 1, for readability only, not needed in solution}
- HRE1 {1/6/2010 11:00 - 1/6/2010 12:00} - Intersects 2
- HRE2 {1/6/2010 11:00 - 1/6/2010 12:00} - Intersects 2
- {End Time Split 2, for readability only, not needed in solution}
- HRE1 {1/6/2010 12:00 - 1/6/2010 14:00} - Intersects 3
- HRE2 {1/6/2010 12:00 - 1/6/2010 14:00} - Intersects 3
- HRE3 {1/6/2010 12:00 - 1/6/2010 14:00} - Intersects 3
- {End Time Split 3, for readability only, not needed in solution}
- HRE1 {1/6/2010 14:00 - 1/6/2010 15:00} - Intersects 2
- HRE2 {1/6/2010 14:00 - 1/6/2010 15:00} - Intersects 2
- {End Time Split 4, for readability only, not needed in solution}
- HRE2 {1/6/2010 15:00 - 1/6/2010 18:00} - Intersects 1
- {End Time Split 5, for readability only, not needed in solution}
- HR4 {1/6/2010 18:00 - 1/6/2010 20:00} - Intersects 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you solve the problem for *two* time intervals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var timePoints = (from r in ranges select r.Start)
    .Concat(from r in ranges select r.End)
    .Distinct().OrderBy(dt => dt).ToArray();

var intersections = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, timePoints.Length - 1)
                    let start = timePoints[i]
                    let end = timePoints[i + 1]
                    from range in ranges
                    where range.Start <= start && range.End >= end
                    select new { Range = range, Start = start, End = end };
```

**EDIT:** Modified code that counts intersections:

```
var timePoints = (from r in ranges select r.Start)
    .Concat(from r in ranges select r.End)
    .Distinct().OrderBy(dt => dt).ToArray();

var intersectionGroups = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, timePoints.Length - 1)
                         let start = timePoints[i]
                         let end = timePoints[i + 1]
                         select new
                         {
                             Start = start,
                             End = end,
                             Ranges =
                                 from range in ranges
                                 where range.Start <= start && range.End >= end
                                 select range
                         };

var intersections = from intGroup in intersectionGroups
                    let count = intGroup.Ranges.Count()
                    from range in intGroup.Ranges
                    select new
                    {
                        Range = range,
                        Start = intGroup.Start,
                        End = intGroup.End,
                        Count = count
                    };
```

I don't know what do you want to do with the result, but it may be better to use `intersectionGroups` rather than `intersections`.

Comment: WOW! This is very close to what I am looking for.  At first I didn't get it but after running through it in VS it made sense after a minute.  Two small things come to mind, and one is my fault since I didn't put it in the original post.

First, it doesn't tell me how many other ranges overlap it.  So for the 11:00 to 12:00 time range the value would be 2.  Maybe an additional property called OverlapCount or something.

Second: This is the case I didn't mention.  Items that are in the array that don't overlap anything are dropped.  Is there a way we can keep them?  I added this to the post.

Comment: My code doesn't drop ranges that don't overlap with anything (like HR4 in your example). I'll have a look at the counts.

Comment: svick, that my friend is a thing of beauty. I actually had developed a solution to the problem before posting but it was so horid I knew there had to be a simple solution. Once again linq saves the day. Thanks again for the assistance svick.